# SwiftUI 4 ImageRenderer doesn't render user input

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, ios16, macos-ventura

The new `ImageRenderer()` in SwiftUI 4 doesn't render user input:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(
            uiImage: ImageRenderer(content: ViewToRender()).uiImage!
        )
        
    }
}

struct ViewToRender: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Input", text: .constant(""))
        Toggle("Toggle", isOn: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

[image]

What do I have to do to render user inputs?

Comment: Looks like a bug, submit feedback to Apple - maybe they fix it till autumn release.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: Any progress on this? I am still hitting this in Feb 2023

Comment: @user1974376 nope